# How to show exception in Visual Studio for SQL CE?

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have a WPF C# project with SQL CE database. Whenever the code involve SQL that throws an exception. I only say XmlParseException but didn't tell me what's causing the error. Is there a way to see these exception related to SQL code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried checking if there is an inner exception and seeing what it says?

```
...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.InnerException != null)
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No Inner Exception");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/55416#362888